# I want to genarete report from different modals which are related by foriegn key

Tags: python, django

```
class ReporttListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Assignments
    
    context_object_name='assignments'
    template_name="workshop/report.html"
    login_url='workshop:custom_login'
    def get_queryset(self):
    
        # Filter the assignments by is_valid=True and prefetch the related item and component models
        return Assignments.objects.filter(is_valid=True).prefetch_related('item', 'item__component_set')


class Item(models.Model):
    """
    This is the item model  has five fields name,stock_id,serial_no,
    status(pending,accepted,completed,not maintable),remark
    """
    ws_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    received_date=models.DateField(auto_now=1)
    stock_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Serial_no =models.CharField(max_length=15)
    delivered_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    received_by= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(choices=(
          ('pending', "pending"),
          ('on_prograss', "On_progress"),
           ('completed', "Completed"),
            ('Not maintainable', "Not maintanable"),
          ),default='pending' ,
          auto_created=True
          )
    remark= models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_valid=models.BooleanField(auto_created=True,default=True)
    is_accepted=models.BooleanField(auto_created=True,default=False)
    is_maintainable=models.BooleanField(auto_created=True,default=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.Serial_no
    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return reverse("workshop:item")
    
class Component(models.Model):
    recived_date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='components')
    stock_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Serial_no =models.CharField(max_length=15)
    is_valid=models.BooleanField(auto_created=True,default=True)

    
 

    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.Serial_no
    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return reverse("workshop:component")

class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_valid=models.BooleanField(default=True)

   
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
class Assignments(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    engineer= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Section= models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remark= models.TextField(blank=True)
    Assigned_date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    completed_date=models.DateField(default="2023-11-02",auto_created=True)
    is_valid=models.BooleanField(auto_created=True,default=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.item)
```

I want my report contains list of components that is related to every assigned  Item . In orrder to achieve this role . I have the above class based view. but my system did not work.It show me the below error.
AttributeError at /report
Cannot find 'component_set' on Item object, 'item__component_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()